# Angular auxiliary outlets weird activation

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I wanted to activate outlets at the same time without using the "ugly" auxiliary outlet URL syntax.

And after playing with it, I have been surprised with the activation mechanism.

- With this routing configuration:

```
{ path: 'test', component: Test1Component },
{ path: 'test', component: Test2Component, outlet: 'two' },
{ path: 'test', component: Test3Component, outlet: 'three' }
```

and this root template:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="two"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="three"></router-outlet>
```

when navigating to `/test`, I thought the 3 outlets would be implicitly activated, but only the primary is.

- Now with all 3 empty paths:

```
{ path: '', component: Test1Component },
{ path: '', component: Test2Component, outlet: 'two' },
{ path: '', component: Test3Component, outlet: 'three' }
```

when navigating to `/`, the 3 outlets are activated!

- And with the 2 auxiliary routes only:

```
{ path: 'test', component: Test2Component, outlet: 'two' },
{ path: 'test', component: Test3Component, outlet: 'three' }
```

when navigating to `/test`, I get `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test'`, I have to individually & explicitly target the outlets: `/(two:test//three:test)`, for the 2 outlets to be activated.

Could someone please explain all this?

Answer (score 1):

The URL `/test` is equivalent to `/(primary:test)`.  All routes (including Auxiliary routes) are resolved the same way - using the path property.

For example:

`/test(two:test//three:test)` is equivalent to `/(primary:test//two:test//three:test)`

In the first case, the reason why `/` will activate all three outlets is because it resolves to:
`/(primary://two://three:)`

But in the second case, `/test` will only resolve the primary outlet because it resolves to `/(primary:test//two://three:)`

If you want to resolve all three outlets in the second case, you would need to: `/test(two:test//three:test)` OR `/(primary:test//two:test//three:test)`

Answer (score 0):

If an empty route is used

```
{ path: '',pathMatch:'full',component: Test1Component}
```

The above several examples of understanding

```
  {path: 'c', component: CComponent,children:[
        {path: 'd', component: DComponent,outlet:'left'},
        {path: 'e', component: EComponent},
   ]},

router.navigate([{outlets: {left: 'd',primary:'e'}}], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

We found that by setting the value to null, our left exit was gone

```
this.router.navigate([{outlets: {left: null,primary:'e'}}], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

I hope it helps you, and I don't want to write it in 'navigateByURL'